# Are there "light bayonets"?

Tags: star-wars, technology, lightsaber

Are there lightsaber-type bayonet rifle attachments in the universe, canon or Legends?

Comment: At least there is [Ezra's lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ezra's_lightsaber)

Comment: @Schweinryder While not technically a bayonet (as it doesn't detach) I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: If I am to nitpick, Ezra's is more like a lightsaber with a pistol attachment. Bayonets, in the form I am familiar with, are blades attached at the end of a rifle barrel and designed to function like a short pike. After seeing so many clones in close quarters with droids - especially commando droids - I wonder why nobody thought to equip them for emergency melee - aren't they also supposed to kill Jedi?

Comment: But I'm not looking at just the Clone Wars. Just want to know if such a thing is known to exist at any point in-universe.

Comment: Using a lightsaber as a bayonet would certainly be technically feasible, but given the typical Jedi preference for melee combat and distaste for blasters, I find it highly unlikely that a Jedi would use his saber for a bayonet. Perhaps if the lightsaber was acquired by someone who couldn't use the Force.

Comment: In Legends, it is possible to construct lightsabers without using the Force, but the physics involved means it is very easy for a non-Force sensitive to lop his head off. A bayonet, however, is different. The rifle is just as easy to control as a melee weapon as though the blade isn't there. And you're much less likely to accidentally point a rifle back at yourself. In canon, lightsabers are harder to manufacture but easier for non-sensitives to use, implying more weight in the blade. Either way, I think the only issue is a matter of manufacture.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: All info here comes from [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=Bayonet&fulltext=Search&page=1&ns0=1&ns14=1&ns112=1)*

**No.  Nothing in canon, but there is some stuff in Legends:**

A [vibrobayonet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vibrobayonet) which is basically a bayonet that vibrates fast.

A [stun bayonet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stun_bayonet) which works on an energy cell and stuns the opponent.  This seems closest to what you want.